# How to solve 404 not found on consul of Golang when i Regist a gin service

Tags: go, web-services, consul

The detail is:

1. the concul is install on the remove server
2. i develop the gin web-server on my PC at home
3. in order for concul to find my ip address, i did an NAT-DDNS, the code is

```golang
func Register(address string, port int, name string, tags []string, id string) error {
    cfg := api.DefaultConfig()
    cfg.Address = "xxxxxx:8500" // consul server address

    client, err := api.NewClient(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    
    registration := new(api.AgentServiceRegistration)

    check := &api.AgentServiceCheck{
        HTTP:                           "http://xxxxxx:80/health", // the NAT outside addr
        Timeout:                        "5s",
        Interval:                       "5s",
        DeregisterCriticalServiceAfter: "10s",
    }
    registration.Name = name
    registration.Port = port
    registration.Tags = tags
    registration.ID = id
    registration.Address = address
    registration.Check = check

    err = client.Agent().ServiceRegister(registration)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return nil
}

func AllServices() {

}

func main() {
    err := Register("the NAT outside addr", 80, "gin-web", []string{"Test", "golang", "consul"}, "gin-web")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

but i failed, the web-server find 404 get request "/health"

| 404 |            0s |       127.0.0.1 | GET      "/health"

Comment: Do you have a route to /health that return status 200 ok in your application?

Comment: You need and register using external service api, not the agent api, agent api used when you run your consul agent in the local and expose it using your nat